# Pandas: Aggregating and applying multiple functions to same column

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
n = 6000
my_data = DataFrame ({
    "Category"  : np.random.choice (['cat1','cat2'], size=n) ,
    "val_1"     : np.random.randn(n) ,
    "val_2"     : [i for i in range (1,n+1)]
})
```

I want to calculate the count of one column and the means of the other two, aggregating by `Category`.  This is described in the pandas documentation as ["Applying different functions to DataFrame columns"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns), and I do it like this:

```
counts_and_means = \
    my_data.groupby("Category").agg (
        {
            "Category"  : np.count_nonzero ,
            "val_1"     : np.mean ,
            "val_2"     : np.mean
        }
    )
```

I also want to calculate a t-test p-variable for `val_2`, testing the hypothesis that the mean of `val_2` is zero. If `val_2` were the only column I was doing anything with throughout this whole process, I could just do what is described in the Pandas documentation as ["Applying multiple functions at once."](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once)  However, I'm trying to do both multiple columns AND multiple functions. I can explicitly name output columns when it's just the "multiple functions at once" case, but I can't figure out how to do it when there are also multiple columns involved.  Right now when I try to do this all in one `agg(...)` step, the `val_2` p-value column definition overwrites the original mean column definition, because they're both in the same `dict`.  So, I end up needing to create a second `DataFrame` and joining them:

```
val_tests = \
    my_data.groupby("Category").agg (
        {
            "val_2"     : lambda arr : sp.stats.ttest_1samp(arr, popmean=0)[1]
        }
    ) \
    .rename (columns={"val_2" : "p_val_2"})

results = pd.merge(counts_and_means, val_tests, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

My question: is there some way to do this all in one `agg(...)` step, without having to create a second result `DataFrame` and performing the `merge`?

(See my other closely-related `agg` question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721666/pandas-best-practices-idioms-for-renaming-reordering-columns-while-aggregating).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.  I'm passing a list of functions for val_2

```
def ttest(arr):     
    return stats.ttest_1samp(arr, popmean=0)[1]

counts_and_means = \
    my_data.groupby("Category").agg (
        {
            "Category"  : np.count_nonzero ,
            "val_1"     : np.mean ,
            "val_2"     : [np.mean,ttest]
        }
    )
```

if you prefer a slightly shorter version

```
counts_and_means = \
    my_data.groupby("Category").agg (
        {
            "Category"  : np.count_nonzero ,
            "val_1"     : np.mean ,
            "val_2"     : [np.mean,lambda arr : stats.ttest_1samp(arr, popmean=0)[1]]
        }
    )
```

This yields

```
     Category      val_1            val_2
         count_nonzero  mean        mean    ttest
Category                
cat1     3059           0.007861    2990.997712 0
cat2     2941          -0.007450    3010.383543 0
```

Per your comment below, you can "flatten" your columns

You can drop a level

```
counts_and_means.columns = counts_and_means.columns.droplevel()
counts_and_means
```

but that removes the top level leaving you duplicate column names

```
           count_nonzero    mean        mean       ttest
Category                
cat1       3059             0.007861    2990.997712 0
cat2       2941            -0.007450    3010.383543 0
```

This might be a better option.  It uses a list comp to concat your column names which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index)

```
counts_and_means.columns = ['%s%s' % (a, '_%s' % b if b else '') 
                           for a, b in counts_and_means.columns]
counts_and_means

            Category_count_nonzero  val_1_mean  val_2_mean   val_2_ttest
Category                
cat1        3059                    0.007861    2990.997712  0
cat2         2941                  -0.007450    3010.383543  0
```

Comment: This looks great, though I must confess I am new to `MultiIndex`, which is what the resulting `DatafFrame` has.  Do you know a way of "flattening" the `MultiIndex` into a regular 1-dimensional index of columns?

Comment: Yeah, i think I know what you mean.  I'll modify my answer